# NSIS Welcome Image stretching

Tags: nsis

I have a bitmap 164x314 with my logo which is showing just fine.

When I use header to resize my installer

```
!include "nsResize.nsh"
```

and add width and height to it

```
!define AddWidth 100u
!define AddHeight 75u
```

I also change dimensions of my bitmap to 164x436 and my logo is looking ugly and stretchy.
Even if I use

```
!define AddHeight 122
```

or

```
!define MUI_WELCOMEFINISHPAGE_BITMAP_NOSTRETCH
```

it don't do much.

What am I missing?

[Left — original, right — NSIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVfDL.png)

Comment: 100u are DPI units, will never be pixel perfect..

Comment: Please post a picture(s), is resizing bitmaps fine for you?

Comment: If I use pixels for !define AddHeight pics are not perfect too. I tried AddHeight 100—110, still nothing good as default. I got dimensions of the bitmap from winexp.exe.

Comment: Added example pic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem with using 0px intro file

```
File "/oname=$PluginsDir\modern-wizard.bmp" "${}\Intro\intro0.bmp"
${NSD_SetImage} "$mui.WelcomePage.Image"    "$PLUGINSDIR\modern-wizard.bmp" "$mui.WelcomePage.Image.Bitmap"
${NSD_SetImage} "$mui.FinishPage.Image"     "$PLUGINSDIR\modern-wizard.bmp" "$mui.FinishPage.Image.Bitmap"
```

and setting image later:

```
${NSD_CreateBitmap} 0 0 164 436 ""
Pop $9
File "/oname=$pluginsdir\welcomeimg.bmp" "${}\Intro\intro96.bmp"
${NSD_SetImage} $9 "$pluginsdir\welcomeimg.bmp" $1
```